# Firebase Function: Custom Sound in notification payload is not running node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make a trademark notification sound in the payload for firebase function using node.js

Here is my Payload..

```
             const payload = {
             notification: {
             title: "Notification From: " + from_name,
             body : from_message,
             icon : "notification.png",
             sound: "orion.mp3"
             }
```

But when I am sending the notification, I am getting the default sound. Not the one I am trying to run.

I have placed the orion.mp3 file in the raw folder as well.

I am unable to understand why it is going like this.